# iOS and Basic offline app

Tags: ios, dictionary, offline, mapbox

I know about mapxbox/routeme and routeme but I need something basic. I need a basic map with all the countries and the only details it would be the name of the countries and the borders.
Can I do that with mapbox? Is there any easier way to do that? 
The app should be offline and preload the maps.

Comment: Do you mean cache manifest?

Comment: I dont know if this is how they call it but I want a static-offlinemap which will look like this one( http://tiles.mapbox.com/mavris/map/map-9vu4vi8e )

Answer (score 10):

iOS 7 support offline maps.

You just need to add tiles for specific area.

Tile contains overlay of map so we just need to add that overlay on the map.

For tiles you need to calculate area for which you need offline map and then get that area from [OpenStreetMaps](http://www.openstreetmap.org).

That's it.

Here is detailed [Link](http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2014/01/21/custom-and-offline-maps-using-overlay-tiles/) tutorial for this.

After getting idea from tutorial you can easily understand the map structure and move ahead.

Cheers.