# Embed Offline Maps into IOS Application

Tags: ios, dictionary, offline

How is it possible to embed offline maps into iOS application?
Do apple maps or google maps provide that ability? I've came across MapBox as but dont understand well how does it work and if it provides that ability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use alternative map kits, for example Nutiteq Maps SDK: http://developer.nutiteq.com , offline maps for iOS (and Android), supports Xamarin IDE (C#) and native languages (ObjectiveC, Swift).

It is more focused to professional apps and complex maps with interactive layers (points, lines and polygons on top of maps), you can even add 3D objects to map. One advantage is that you can use your own base map sources (in-house, 3rd parties), not only OpenStreetMap what SDK itself provides.

Disclaimer: I'm developer of it.

Comment: the most importain question is: Does it free?

Comment: It is "free" in terms of open source: https://github.com/CartoDB/mobile-sdk . Professional support and server services are never free.

Comment: no. I saw 30-day free trial, after that every request got unauthorized.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Apple maps support offline maps.

Visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903416/ios-and-basic-offline-app/23407721#23407721) for detailed answer.

Also you can download source code from this [link](https://github.com/viggiosoft/MapTileOverlayTutorial).