# google maps Offline into iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, offline

How to embed google maps Offline into iOS App,

Can I add google maps on applications that use offline maps feature?
I have an application that uses the navigation. Maps I use Mapbox apropos for navigation Mapbox less than perfect so I try to use google maps, but there are obstacles. first Mapbox I use is offline maps, so now want to try to move to google and google maps whether there are offline for the embed

Comment: Well, you can try to check this [Github](https://github.com/mapsme/api-ios) if it can help you. MAPS.ME is an offline maps API for iOS that provides an interface for other applications to perform the different tasks including the offline maps. 

For more information, you can also check this related [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513952/embed-offline-maps-into-ios-application).