# Xamarin.forms maps offline

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, xamarin.forms

I want to use xamarin.forms maps offline with google maps.

I know how to do it in xamarin for android - using MapTypeNone, and loading the my own TileProvider.

Is there a way to do it also in xamarin.forms instead of using different code for android and IOS ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Dependency service/Custom Renderer to separate that code, not sure if it is possible to use Google Maps but there are other options like:

https://components.xamarin.com/view/nutiteqmapssdk

and

[iOS and Basic offline app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903416/ios-and-basic-offline-app/23407721#23407721)

Hope this helps.